# touchesBegan usage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering the usage function of touchesBegan in Swift. Can I use it in order to know if a button is being pressed? Can you please make an example of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of `touchesBegan()` is not for a button. The method can be used without any other declaration or code to show that a finger touched on the screen. There are the companion functions `touchesMoved()` that shows that the finger moved and `touchesEnded()` to show the finger let go. Also there is the function `touchesCancelled()` that indicates that the touch was cancelled.

Here is an example:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("finger touched the screen...")
}
```

To detect whether a button was pressed you use its target & selector:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

In the following function your button gets fired:

```
func buttonPressed(button: UIButton!) {
    print("button was pressed")
}
```

Depending on the `UIControlEvent` you can trigger the button by pressing and letting go, touching it, touching and moving the finger away, etc..

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: By the way can I ask you if you can help me a bit with Bluetooth data transferring? Do you know some reference I can relate to? Or do you know how it works?